# How can I use Prettier to get closing HTML tags on a new line?

Tags: html, tags, markup, prettier

I'm trying to achieve the following output with Prettier when writing plain HTML:

```
<div class="foo"></div>

<div
  class="foo"
  id="bar"
>
</div>
```

Note how the closing div tag on a div with multiple attributes is on a separate line (and all container on one line for a div with a single / no attributes).

I believe  `--jsx-bracket-same-line` set to false achieves the desired outcome in JSX, but I'm trying to achieve this in regular HTML.

I am open to using other plugins or ESLint settings with Prettier.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have HTML files, then you can change the default parser to `lwc` instead of `HTML`. This change will turn all parsers to `lwc`

```
{
    "parser": "lwc"
}
```

In the case where you have multiple different filetypes, better to only apply for `*.html` files then put the following into your `.prettierrc.`

```
{
  "overrides": [{ "files": "*.html", "options": { "parser": "lwc" } }]
}
```